# What are the references needed to support Web Forms and User Controls

Tags: webforms

I know the 3 references necessary for MVC are Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences, Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences, and Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.NoReferences.

But I have a legacy project I need to work on and need to know the correct references to add to my C# ASP.net project for Web Forms and User Control support in sitecore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answered so I will post this as an answer as it worked for me.

This applies to VS projects created outside of the Sitecore local instance.

For my Web Forms project, I used Sitecore.Kernel and Sitecore.Web.  Make sure to install the right revision for your Sitecore install files and set Copy Local to false for all of your project references that are already in Sitecore's bin folder.  That way, publishing your project can't break your local instance.

If anyone comes up with a better answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can accept your answer @Brett Drake as you have figured it put by your own :)